# slideshow in asp.net C# stops at first image

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, eventtrigger

I learning asp.net. In this exercise what I'm trying to achieve is compile a 3 image slide show. The page compiles and shows only the first image. The page is suppose to update or refresh to show each image in 2 second intervals. Basing my code on another program that worked which used a conditional statement, the basic difference is that I'm using an array in addition to a conditional if statement.  I didn't use the Trigger element because the code I'm basing mine on didn't us it. This is a excerpt from the lecture notes: "The  control specifies a control and event that will cause a partial page update for the UpdatePanel that contains this trigger reference. The ControllD attribute sets the name of the control that triggers an asynchronous postback for an UpdatePanel control." For some reason I believe my problem may lies here. But because I'm new I really don't know. That's why I come here for help. please. If someone could just point me in the right directions I think I can get this program to work the way it's suppose to. Here is the code

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" %>
 <script runat="server" type="text/vb">
 private void Timer1_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 string[] circle = new string[3];
 circle[0]="red";
 circle[1]="green";
 circle[2]="blue";
 int i = Convert.ToInt32(circle);
 i = i + 1;
 if (i > 3)
 { 
 i = 1;
 }
 image1.ImageUrl = "red " + i + ".png";
  }
 </script>
 <!Doctype html>
 <html>
 <body>
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
 <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" id="ScriptManager1">
 </asp:ScriptManager>
 <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional">
 <ContentTemplate>
 <asp:Timer runat="server" id="Timer1" Interval="2000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" />
 <asp:Image id="image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="red.png"  AlternateText="Circles" />
 </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295400.aspx) example. Nowadays, it is more common practice to solve this problem via javascript. Look also at compile and browser errors (use F12)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgive me for the poor commenting but today I'm in hurry. 
I'm assuming the code is only for educational purposes. Javascript is better tailored for the task you want to accomplish. c# or every server side language is espected to make a round trip (page is reloaded) on the server every refresh

You need to make the slide counter variable persistent across postback. 
There are many ways to accomplish the task Database, Session Variables, ViewState object (perhaps the last is the best one but and you can work on it).

Here is a little variation of your code. Hope it helps.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager1">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Timer runat="server" ID="Timer1" Interval="2000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" />
                <asp:Label Text="no images loaded" ID="LabelImageName" runat="server" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

<script runat="server" type="text/vb">

string[] _arrImgNames = new string[] { "red", "green", "blue" };


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        // set counter session variable only the first time the page is loaded (not when script refreshs)
        Session["counter"] = -1;
    }
}


private void Timer1_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string textToShow = String.Format(
        "Now the program shows image '{0}' "
        , this.GetNextSlideImageName());

    LabelImageName.Text = textToShow;

}


private string GetNextSlideImageName()
{
    // get the counter from session variable 
    int counter = Convert.ToInt32(Session["counter"]);

    // increase the counter 
    counter++;

    if (counter >= this._arrImgNames.Length)
    {
        counter = 0;
    }

    // updating the session variable 
    Session["counter"] = counter;

    // compose the image name 
    string imageName = String.Format("{0}.png", this._arrImgNames[counter]);

    return imageName;
}

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. This gives me a different aspect to ponder. I'm gonna have to make  a few tweaks but this helps me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to pull the C# code out and see what happen in console?

I guess you cannot convert a string array to an integer

```
int i = Convert.ToInt32(circle);
```

do you mean

```
int i = circle.Length?
```

Edit:

Beside of you are not having the correct "i" yet (which you can add a piece of logic to parse image1.ImageUrl and get the current index), I guess your

```
 image1.ImageUrl = "red " + i + ".png";
```

is actually

```
 image1.ImageUrl = circle[i - 1] + ".png";
```

Edit2:

To get the "i" you want, assuming your image are always xxx.png and xxx is always exist in the circle array, you can substring the imageURL by location of the dot to get the "xxx", then find the matching string in the circle array, and get the index of it.

Comment: No I didn't try to isolate the code. I was trying to make it work in asp,net. No I didn't use circle.length. But I'm going to try now. You say I can't convert a string array to an integer? It seems to me that I did.

Comment: I tried int i = circle.Length and nothing changed. The page compiled but it didn't refresh to show the other images. Or maybe it did refresh. But I'm only seeing the one red circle. Oh, in the console  I get an error that it was expecting an expression but got ]. Whatever that means.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem lay in the array initialization. Every thick the object is created brand new along with the counter.

```
string[] circle = new string[3];
circle[0]="red"; 
circle[1]="green";
circle[2]="blue"; 
int i = Convert.ToInt32(circle);
```

This cause the fact the counter is reset to it's starting value for every thick.
I better move the initialization code somewhere outside the Timer1_Tick function.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm new so I'm going to have to ask you to be a little more specific, please. I removed the if statement. And initialized i to i = circle.Length. Now I'm trying to understand the Timer1_Tick function you just mentioned. And then you said move the initialization code outside the Timer1_Tick function. I'm looking at that, trying to grasp what you mean.